# How to connect socket.io in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, sockets

Good morning why this code don't work (server respond but "io.on" no):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//this code not work in console // even it can not see
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('a user connect');
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('a user disconnect');
        });
    });

//server respond
http.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('Server running at 3000');
    });
```

I'm a beginner, express and socket.io i downloaded by npm

Comment: What code are you running in the client to connect to socket.io?

Comment: app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Server and socket works');
    })

Comment: So, you are making an HTTP request from your client code but not running a socket.io client in your client code, right? (e.g., from the [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) package)

Comment: you were right Thanks now it's works

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a server as well as a client which will make a connection to the socket io server.

Based on what I understood from your code, I guess you want to do something like this:

First your server.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io');

var port = 3000;
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);

var socketio = io.listen(server);

setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Emitting..");
    socketio.emit('data', {"x":"123"}); 
}, 2000);

module.exports = app;
```

Then your client.html: (I am writing a client, which will log into browser console.)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/");

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
       console.log('disconnected');
    });

    socket.on("data", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

That's it. Now start your server with `node server.js` and then, open up `client.html` in your browser and check console. Let me know, if there's anything unclear.